# Can't get UITableView to scroll inside my SlidingPanel

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin, mvvmcross

I've got a UITableView located in a View attached to a SlidingPanel.

I'm using [SlidingPanels.Lib](https://github.com/patbonecrusher/SlidingPanels.Touch/tree/master/SlidingPanels/SlidingPanels.Lib), and I've got a custom presenter

[Here's a gist of the custom presenter](https://gist.github.com/ChaseFlorell/8511367)

From there my `MenuView` is really straight forward.

```
public class MenuView : ViewControllerBase
{
    private new MenuViewModel ViewModel { get { return (MenuViewModel)base.ViewModel; } }

    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();

        // todo: this should actually be...
        // _currentBookId = currentUser.UserBooks[0].BookId;
        // _homeViewModel.ChapterViewModel = Mvx.Resolve<IChapterService>().FindByBookId(_currentBookId);
        ViewModel.Chapters = Mvx.Resolve<IChapterService>().Find();

        // this ensures the sliding panel doesn't fill the entire view.
        var frame = View.Frame;
        frame.Width = 300;
        View.Frame = frame;

        // var currentUser = Mvx.Resolve<IUserService>().GetById(Mvx.Resolve<UserModel>().Id);

        var label = new UILabel(new RectangleF(10, 10, 300, 40))
        {
            TextColor = UIColor.White,

        };
        Add(label);

        //var listHeight = (chapters.Count*40);
        var navigationList = new UITableView(new RectangleF(0, 50, 300, 300))
            {
                Source = new NavigationTableSource(ViewModel.Chapters)
            };
        Add(navigationList);

        var set = this.CreateBindingSet<MenuView, MenuViewModel>();
        set.Bind(label).To(vm => vm.DisplayName);
        set.Apply();
    }
}
```

Unfortunately I'm not sure where to look in order to allow the TableView to scroll. I can see it, but it goes beyond the bottom of the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took a couple of hours of dicking around to discover that the original source code that I grabbed from @patbonecrusher's [Github repo](https://github.com/patbonecrusher/SlidingPanels.Touch) had some differences from the lib that you can find at @fcaico's [Github repo](https://github.com/fcaico/MvxSlidingPanels.Touch)

Long story short... all I had to do was compile @fcaico's version and deploy it into my app, and the scrolling came back. Now I realize that @fcaico's repo just contains a submodule to @patbonecrusher's, but for some reason... the recompile fixed the issue. Don't have a lot of time to dig into the reason why.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in:

```
        var listHeight = (chapters.Count*40);
```

Instead of this, try setting the height to the height of the available screen (which depends on which iPhone/iPad you are on). After this, then the list will scroll within that available height.

Comment: I actually tried setting the height to 300 (which is less that the height of the view) and it still refused to scroll.

Comment: I just updated my question and removed that line from the example. Sorry @stuart for making your current answer irrelevant.